# Job DSL support for jenkins promoted build plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I want to enable build promotion in my release job, which I would like to promote the build to production repository manually, is there a dsl support for this plugin ? If now how can I use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in support, but there is an open feature request filed as [JENKINS-21750](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21750) and there is an open [pull request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/promoted-builds-plugin/pull/82). So people are working on this and it should be available soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the [Promoted Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin), then you can use a `configure` block until support is added to the Job DSL plugin. I suggest adding a promotion step to a job manually using the UI, looking at the `config.xml` that Jenkins generates for that job and using that to find out the node names and hierarchy. For example, here is how to configure a simple manual promotion step called "ready to rock":

```
{ project ->
    (project / 'properties' / 'hudson.plugins.promoted__builds.JobPropertyImpl' / 'activeProcessNames' / 'string').setValue('ready to rock')
}
```